# How to solve this CPLEX exception?

Tags: java, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I have made a program to solve a (non trivial) optimization problem with CPLEX. I have reviewed the code and the modelisation several times and I don't see problems. However, when I launch the process, the following error message appears :

> Concert exception ’ilog.cplex.CpxException: CPLEX Error 5002: Q in ''q1'' is not positive semi-definite

Does it imply that there is a mistake in my stuff or is there a trick to avoid this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You have a quadratic term (variable times variable) in your model. Cplex can only solve certain classes of quadratic problems: the model has to be convex (with some exceptions). Non-convex models can sometimes be reformulated. In some cases, a piecewise linear formulation can help. Otherwise, consider a global solver.

Answer (score -1):

The link below give solutions for some cases of quadratic terms. This document can help you about how to handle quadratic terms if your case is one of them mentioned in the document.

http://ampl.com/MEETINGS/TALKS/2013_07_Rome_WB9.pdf